# Getting the value of a field in the default language in django-transmeta

Tags: python, django, django-transmeta

I'm using django-transmeta to help with my multi-lingual models. Here's an example model of mine:

```
class Edition(models.Model):

    __metaclass__ = TransMeta

    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Could anyone tell me how I can get the value of the `name` field in the default language. I'd like to override the `__unicode__` method of the model so I can display a meaningful title. Currently it is displayed as `Edition Object` and is not very helpful.

Thanks.

---

Edit: I've managed to do it like this but this relies on the fact the language code is hardcoded.

```
class Edition(models.Model):

    __metaclass__ = TransMeta

    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

def __unicode__(self):

    return self.name_en
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi I am a developer of django-transmeta. For each internationalized field, you have a property with the name field original.

```
edition = Edition.objects.all()[0]
print edition.name
print edition.name_en
print edition.name == edition.name_en
```

If it's not work, you should check LANGUAGE_CODE and TRANSMETA_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE (this is optional) in your settings

Answer (score 1):

ModelTranslation uses the same convention (_en, _fr, ...) but makes use of it transparently depending on the current request language.

https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation

Also, it's still currently active.